# How would I create a while loop that reads a character every iteration and stores that character?

Tags: c, while-loop, character, scanf

For example:

how would I use `scanf` to do this?

```
scanf("%c", &c); 

while(c != '\0')
{
    scanf("%c", &c); 
}
```

Comment: Why not create a string and append the read character to a string? Or do you want a separate variable for each character?

Comment: I'm working on a simple parenthesis checker program using a vector. But I can't get the while loop to work. They way I'd like it to be is.. It reads a character from input.. if the character is a left symbol ([, { , ( ) it stores the character. But I don't know how to create a loop like that.

Comment: Using scanf to read a single character is insane.  Try `getchar` or `getc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost correct. You just need to change

```
while(c != '\0')
```

to

```
while(c != '\n')
```

because the last character the user will enter is the newline character.